# Accessing posts via directory tree in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

Let's say I have a directory like the following:

```
|things
|---|animals
|---|---|dog
|---|---|cat
|---|---|other
|---|languages
|---|---|Afrikaans
|---|---|Latin
|---|---|Japanese
|---|---|other
```

and I want to access all of the posts under the "other" category that is under the "languages" category.

I want to be able to do

```
{% for post in site.categories.things.languages.other do %}
```

but that apparently doesn't work in Jekyll.

If I can avoid it, I'd like to not do

```
{% for post in site.categories.cobol do %}
    {% if post.categories equals ["things", "languages", "other"] %}
```

but if I absolutely must, I will.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply output a list of posts contained in a given path :

**languages_other.html**

```
---
path: "things/languages/other/"
---
{% include post_by_folder.html path=page.path %}
```

**_includes/posts_by_folder.html**

```
<h1>Posts in folder {{ include.path }}</h1>
<ul>
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% if post.path contains include.path %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    </li>
  {%endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Now any time you want to make a list of posts in a particular folder, you just have to create a page like `languages_other.html`.